# MQTT long polling over GPRS/HSDPA

Tags: long-polling, mqtt, gprs

I'd like to use MQTT to send control information to a device, but I'm concerned that leaving the MQTT client and cell data connection up (basically in long-polling mode) is somehow bad. Either from a data charges, network usage, battery life, or some other aspect?

Another approach might be to send an SMS to the device when it has a message to pick up - but that seems to defeat the purpose of MQTT and also introduces a long delay while dialing and setting up the GPRS connection.

Is there any reason I should be concerned on this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach is quite valid - think of it this way: Your App's long polling transfers a very small volume of data, as long as it just polls, so

- the data usage should be miniscule
- the battery is impacted only for the data sent **in addition to the keepalive**, which is at least an order of magnitude higher than the long polling
- as a reference: ActiveSync, which runs all the time, is nothing else than a fancy form of long polling

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at MQTT-SN, which is designed to run over UDP, and therefore does not need an active connection. Real Small Message Broker is an implementation of a MQTT-SN broker, and will bridge to Mosquitto.

The other approach is to use the retain flag on messages, that way a control app can send the message and the device will get it as soon as it reconnects, regards less of if the app is still online. In all cases, the user experience on the app side should differentiate between the request being sent and it being honored, or refused, so you will need tri-state controls (on, off, pending).